# Implementing Reporting in Java Web Application

Tags: java, jsf, reporting, business-intelligence

We have a database. All reports are build upon it. Currently I have made a web application that retrieves data from database and shows in JSF data table. Since these report are based on query if query changes or I need to build new report I must change the code or view.

So, my question here is

1. How could we implement reporting without changing code?
2. Is there any way I could embed reporting engine into my reporting tool?

Any suggestions, documentation?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a report engine like jasper report, that allows you to build in an easy and customisable way reports in PDF, excel, XML, HTML...  iReport is  the graphic tool based upon jasper report engine, that allows you to customise the output of your report.

You can download them both here

[jasper report community web site](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library)

With the hope that is will help.

Answer (score 2):

When you plug in a reporting system, you are *always* going to have to do some work specific to each report (or at least to groups of reports) unless you go to a big application that will work along side your application and talk to the database itself allowing business staff or users to build their own reports (think Cognos/Business Objects/Yellow Fin etc).

You can plug in the [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) (Commerical) or [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) (free) engines into your application and use DOC or ODT documents as templates for reports.  These tools can pump out a variety of formats including DOC/ODT/PDF/HTML/RTF etc depending on what type of output you require.  Docmosis can extract data from a database ResultSet so if your query changes the report will reflect the change automatically (as long as the template still makes sense for your change to the SQL).  The good thing about using Doc/Odt documents as templates is that anyone can change the style of your reports.

So, your questions:

1. you need to allow a report system to generate reports based on your queries.  If the query changes the report gets the data from the new query.  If the query is quite different though, the report can't "know" how to display it - so you will often have to change the report layout to match.
2. Yes, JODReports, Docmosis, iText and various others can plug into your Java application

Please note I work for the company that created Docmosis.

Hope that helps.